# How to create authorization roles from OIDC token in WebSphere Liberty server application using social login feature?

Tags: authorization, openid-connect, websphere-liberty, open-liberty, microprofile

I am trying to implement role based authorization in an application running on WebSphere / Open Liberty server. Authentication is implemented using OIDC token & socual-login feature & it is workig fine. I am struggling to create roles from JWT token & depending on that authorizing access to different servlets.

**My server.xml -**

```
<server description="new server">
       <!-- Enable features -->
       <featureManager>
             <feature>appSecurity-3.0</feature>
             <feature>socialLogin-1.0</feature>
             <feature>microProfile-4.1</feature>
             <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
             <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
       </featureManager> 

       <logging traceSpecification="*=info" consoleLogLevel="INFO"/>

       <oidcLogin clientId="${clientId}"
             clientSecret="${clientSecret}"
             discoveryEndpoint="${oAuthServerUrl}/.well-known/openid-configuration"
             id="liberty-aad-oidc-javaeecafe" signatureAlgorithm="RS256"
             userNameAttribute="email" groupNameAttribute="role"/>

       <authFilter id="myAuthFilter">
             <requestUrl id="myRequestUrl" matchType="contains"
                    urlPattern="/*" />
       </authFilter>

       <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore"
             password="${env.keystore_password}" />
       <keyStore id="mytruststore"
             location="${server.config.dir}/mytruststore.jks" password="****" />

       <ssl id="defaultSSLConfig" keyStoreRef="defaultKeyStore"
             trustDefaultCerts="true" trustStoreRef="mytruststore" />

       <applicationManager autoExpand="true" />

       <httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443"
             id="defaultHttpEndpoint" />

       <mpJwt id="myMpJwt"
             jwksUri="${oAuthServerUrl}/publickeys"
             issuer="${oAuthServerUrl}"
             authFilterRef="myAuthFilter" groupNameAttribute="role"/>          

       <applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean" />    

       <applicationMonitor dropinsEnabled="false"/>

       <webApplication contextRoot="/" id="oidcsampleapp"
             location="oidcsampleapp-1.0.0.war" name="oidcsampleapp" >

             <application-bnd>
                    <security-role name="admin-role">
                          <group name="admin" />
                    </security-role>
                    <!-- <security-role name="admin">
                          <special-subject type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS" />
                    </security-role> -->
             </application-bnd>
       </webApplication>
</server>
```

When using  request is forwarded to application, otherwise access is denied. I am trying to create the security principal role "admin-role" which is coming along with the JWT token.

**Web.xml security configuration -**

```
<security-role>
         <role-name>admin-role</role-name>
   </security-role>
   <security-role>
         <role-name>user-role</role-name>
   </security-role>

   <security-constraint>
         <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>AdminServlet</web-resource-name>
                <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
                <http-method>GET</http-method>
                <http-method>PUT</http-method>
                <http-method>POST</http-method>
                <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
         </web-resource-collection>

         <auth-constraint>
                <role-name>admin-role</role-name>
         </auth-constraint>

         <user-data-constraint>
                <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
         </user-data-constraint>
   </security-constraint>
```

Roles defined above are part of the JWT token from OIDC server & mentioned in server.xml.

```
<security-role>
         <role-name>admin-role</role-name>
   </security-role>
   <security-role>
         <role-name>appuser-role</role-name>
   </security-role>

   <security-constraint>
         <web-resource-collection>
                <web-resource-name>AdminServlet</web-resource-name>
                <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
                <http-method>GET</http-method>
                <http-method>PUT</http-method>
                <http-method>POST</http-method>
                <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
         </web-resource-collection>

         <auth-constraint>
                <role-name>admin-role</role-name>
         </auth-constraint>
         <user-data-constraint>
                <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
         </user-data-constraint>
   </security-constraint>
```

**JWT token received:**

```
{
  "iss": https://xxxxx.xxxxx,
  "exp": 1665245032,
  "aud": [
    "931280e3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxx"
  ],
  "sub": "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
  "amr": [
    "saml"
  ],
  "iat": 1665241432,
  "tenant": "xxxxxxxxx",
  "scope": "openid appid_default appid_readuserattr appid_readprofile appid_writeuserattr appid_authenticated",
  "role": "admin-role",
  "surname": "Basu",
  "groups": [
    "014a0054-942f-4c20-a6e0-235dd906ca1c"
  ],

  "entityID": https://sts.windows.net/81fa766e-a349-4867-8bf4-ab35e250a08f/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JWT data the "groups" part seems more like the list of roles, but in server.xml I see it's set to groupNameAttribute="role".
Liberty doesn't seem to be able to use these groups from JWT for declarative  settings unless you also use some UserRegistry in your server.xml, and then try to join things with <oidcLogin mapToUserRegistry="true"...